# Tweet on public_timeline twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter

I received the feed of public_timeline but I want to Tweet on public_timeline twitter.

Please help me how can i tweet on public_timeline in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just want to post a Tweet? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and did you have a look [`TWTweetComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: As per my knowledge TWTeetComposeController is use for tweet on our wall. Is it possible to tweet on public_timeline using TWTeetComposeController?

Comment: There is no `wall` nor `public_timeline` in twitter. You can send a Tweeet to someone, start the tweet with `@<user>`.

Comment: Thanks its true. I am sorry for that. now i understand about that.

Comment: Can i tweet without login on twitter?

Comment: No, you must have an account and be logged in to twitter to send a tweet.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments to your question, you only need to tweet (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) to show up in the public timeline.  However, the reality is that you don't have a guarantee of showing up in the public timeline.  Additionally, getting your tweet to show up anywhere that someone who isn't explicity following you would see can be a challenge, as explained below:

Twitter's public timeline is scheduled for deprecation, as detailed here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline

However, there's never a guarantee that any of your tweets would appear in the public timeline as it has essentially become a random sample of tweets.  This is primarily because the volume of tweets is so large that the REST API can't keep up and the fact that there's a rate limit on the number of queries that can be performed.

The only true option here is streams, but that might not be an option because (1) consuming the firehose (available through 3rd parties) would require scalable infrastructure to handle the volume, (2) a Sample stream wouldn't guarantee that your tweet would appear (being a sample it includes a random set), and (3) a filter stream requires that your tracking terms match what is in a tweet.

So, you can tweet and you have the chance of that tweet appearing in a public stream.  However, there are aspects of how Twitter works that you need to be aware of and evaluate how they fit with your goals.

Joe